# Absolute zero and zero-point energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, temperature, ground-state

What will be the theoretical temperature of ideal solid state matter where all the atoms have only zero-point quantum fluctuation? Is it exactly 0.00000 K or still some 0.000000x K?

Comment: It will be at exactly zero temperature

Comment: How does it match with thermodynamic equations like $E=1/2kT$. When T=0 then energy is zero, but from quantum mechanics point of view zero-point energy is not zero. It looks like kind of paradox.

Comment: You can always add or subtract a constant from the Hamiltonian without altering the physics. The standard statistical mechanics formula typically assume that the ground state of the system has zero energy, i.e. the zero of energy is set such that there is no zero point energy. A system is at absolute zero if and only if it is certain to be in its lowest energy state (whatever the energy of that state may be)

Comment: @Zlelik The equation $E = \frac{1}{2}kT$ isn't general. It holds true for expected average energy per quadratic degree of freedom in classical statistical physics. In practice, for harmonic oscillator, it holds only for high enough temperatures where $\hbar \omega \ll kT$ so classical statistical physics is accurate. But for low enough temperatures, this is not so. For example, expected average energy of harmonic oscillator at low temperature near 0K is $\frac{1}{2}\hbar\omega$, i.e. positive "zero point energy", independent of temperature.

Comment: @BySymmetry one can add a constant to the Hamiltonian, but one can't get rid of zero point fluctuations. These were observed e.g. in X-ray diffraction experiments on rock salt. https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1928.0055

Comment: @JánLalinský Do you agree with By Symmetry that when there are only zero fluctuations temperature is exactly zero, not 0.00000X K?

Comment: @Zlelik yes, if the system had positive temperature, we would expect more fluctuations than just zero point fluctuations.